# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'permissions'. DJango groups

Tags: python, django

I did a bit of research and it seems that this is the correct code according to Django documentations but for some reason it returns.

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'permissions'. DJango groups.
```

Here is the code.

```
        admin_group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Admin')
        admin_group.permissions.add(
            add_token_permission,
            add_user_detail_permission,
            change_user_detail_permission,
            add_user_location_permission,
        )
        admin_group.user_set.add(self.user)
        admin_group.save()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get_or_create` returns a tuple containing the object and a boolean whether the object was newly created or not.

So you would need to do:

```
admin_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Admin')
```

Comment: The test case now passes. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`get_or_create` returns a tuple. Object and created.

```
admin_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Admin')
admin_group.permissions.add(
    add_token_permission,
    add_user_detail_permission,
    change_user_detail_permission,
    add_user_location_permission,
)
admin_group.user_set.add(self.user)
admin_group.save()
```

**[More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The test case now passes.